# Get first element of HTMLCollection after window loads (Joomla)

Tags: javascript, joomla, htmlcollection

I wrote a joomla module and am trying to access a HTMLCollection in a small script.
I added my script file via

```
$document->addScript('templates/design_control/js/mod_articles_newsbox.js');
```

the script itself looks like this:

```
function openNews(id)
{
    var list = document.getElementsByClassName("newsbox");
    console.log(list);
    console.log("newsbox length: " + list.length);
    console.log(list[0]);
    ...
}

if(window.addEventListener){
    window.addEventListener("load", openNews(0), false);
} else {
    window.attachEvent("onload", openNews(0));
}
```

Now the problem is that I can't get the first element of my list. When I log the list itself everything seems fine and I get a list with 1 element. But when I try to log that first element or the length of the list, it is undefined/0.

I don't know, if it's a problem with joomla and how I add the script or the script is executed before the element is ready (which would be odd, because the list itself prints fine) or something else, I only know that I wasted far too much time on this^^ So, do you have any clue how to solve this?

Comment: Where you are placing your js code?if code is in wrapped in <head> then it will give undefined because it will executed before dom is loaded

Comment: Ah okay, yes, the $document->addScript() function places the code inside the head tag... I just tried to place it just above my <ul> element (the "newsbox"), but that gives the same error. How should I add the script?

Comment: It should be executed after DOM is rendered(DOM ready)

Comment: Even if I change the event listener from load to DOMContentLoaded, the list is still empty, when I try to access it. When I print the list itself it shows the element, so it should be there and DOM should be ready, shouldn't it? That's really strange...

Answer (score 0):

try using different javascript event when DOM is loaded:

```
if (window.addEventListener) {
  window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', openNews(0));
} else {
  window.attachEvent('onload', openNews(0));
}
```